# Python regex to replace single newlines and ignore sequences of two or more newlines

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.6 through 3.8.

I'm trying to replace any instance of a single newline with a single space in text read from a file.  My goal is to compress paragraphs into single lines of text for re-wrapping by `textwrap`.  Since `textwrap` only works on a single paragraph I need an easy way to detect/delineate paragraphs, and compressing them into a single line of text seems the most expedient.  In order for this to work, any instance of two or more newlines in sequence define a paragraph boundary and should be left alone.

My first try was with lookahead/lookbehind assertions to insist that any newline I replace not be bounded by other newlines:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)', ' ', input_text)
```

This works fine is most circumstances.  However, I quickly ran into a case where someone had a paragraph separator that contained other whitespace.

> This is some sample text beginning with a short paragraph.\n\nThis second paragraph is long enough to be split across lines, so it contains\na single newline in the middle.\n \nThis third paragraph has an unusual separator before it; a newline followed by\na space followed by another newline.  It's a special case that needs to be\nhandled.

My lookahead/lookbehind assertion tactic won't work here, because the required lookbehind needs to be of an indeterminate length (maybe the space is there, maybe it isn't) and that's not allowed.

```
# this is an error
re.sub(r'(?<!\n\s*)\n(?!\s*\n)', ' ', input_text)
```

My next try was to do this in two passes, removing any non-newline whitespace between newlines, but I can't find a regex that will do that perfectly.  This works, sortof, but will compress any occurrences of more than two newlines.

```
# this compresses "\n\n\n" or "\n\n \n" into "\n\n"
re.sub(r'(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)', ' ', re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', '\n\n', input_text))
```

I'd like to avoid this, because extra blank lines between paragraphs may be intentional; they should be left alone.

The unicode definition of `\s` isn't specific enough to allow me to construct a character set of "all whitespace except newlines", so I can't do something like this:

```
# this only works for ASCII
re.sub(r'(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)', ' ', re.sub(r'\n[ \t\r\f\v]*\n', '\n\n', input_text))
```

To do that I need a way to express "`\s` except `\n`" for unicode and I don't think that exists.  I tried `[\s!\n]` on a lark and, bizarrely, it seems to do the right thing in 3.6.5 and 3.8.0.  This, despite the fact that `!` has no documented effect inside a character set for either version, and that the documentation for `re.escape()` explicitly states that, as of 3.7, `!` is no longer escaped by the method as it's not a special character.

```
# this appears to work, but the docs say it shouldn't
re.sub(r'(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)', ' ', re.sub(r'\n[\s!\n]\n', '\n\n', input_text))
```

Even though it seems to work, I don't want to rely on the behaviour, for obvious reasons.  I should probably report it as a bug in either the code or the documentation.

Assuming that last one is not supposed to be supported, what other approach am I missing?

Comment: can you provide a sample of the text so we can work on it?

Comment: Can you add a small text sample for your problem?

Comment: Can you use `(?<!\n)[ \t]*\n[ \t]*(?!\n)` and just count it as a bonus to get rid of those superfluous spaces?

Comment: There is sample text in the question already.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: That also has the effect of compressing occurrences of more than two newlines into only two.

Comment: Darn, I felt like I failed to consider something. Looks like you received an answer from Wiktor so I can only assume it is the correct answer :)

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit; your question should remain strictly a question. If you want to add something to the accepted answer, you are encouraged to post an answer of your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may capture the occurrences of double and more newlines to keep them when matched and just match all other newlines:

```
import re
text = "This is some sample text beginning with a short paragraph.\n\nThis second paragraph is long enough to be split across lines, so it contains\na single newline in the middle.\n \nThis third paragraph has an unusual separator before it; a newline followed by\na space followed by another newline. It's a special case that needs to be\nhandled."
print( re.sub(r'([^\S\n]*\n(?:[^\S\n]*\n)+[^\S\n]*)|[^\S\n]*\n[^\S\n]*', lambda x: x.group(1) or ' ', text) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/LRY447)

**Details**

- `([^\S\n]*\n(?:[^\S\n]*\n)+[^\S\n]*)` - Group 1: 0+ whitespaces other than a newline, a newline, then 1 or more (so, at least two newlines are matched) occurrences of 0+ whitespaces other than a newline and a newline, and then again 0+ whitespaces other than a newline
- `|`  - or
- `[^\S\n]*\n[^\S\n]*` - 0+ whitespaces other than a newline, a newline and again 0+ whitespaces other than a newline

The replacement is `lambda x: x.group(1) or ' '`: if Group 1 matched, no replacement should occur, else, replace with a space.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  You also identified the correct expression of "\s except \n" for me, which fixes my last example:  `re.sub(r'(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)', ' ', re.sub(r'\n[^\S\n]\n', '\n\n', input_text))`